# Inline bash script variables

Tags: bash

Admittedly, I'm a bash neophyte.  I always want to reach for Python for my shell scripting purposes.  However, I'm trying to push myself to learn some bash.  I'm curious why the following code doesn't work.

```
sh -c "F=\"123\"; echo $F"
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It doesn't work because variable expansion in the double-quoted string happens *before* the command is called.  That is, if I type:

```
echo "$HOME"
```

The shell transforms this into:

```
echo "/home/lars"
```

Before actually calling the echo command.  Similarly, if you type:

```
sh -c "F=\"123\"; echo $F"
```

This gets transformed into:

```
sh -c "F=\"123\"; echo"
```

Before calling a the `sh` command.  You can use single quotes to inhibit variable expansion, for example:

```
sh -c 'F="123"; echo $F'
```

You can also escape the `$` with a backslash:

```
sh -c "F=\"123\"; echo \$F"
```

Comment: Also, if you're trying to learn `bash`, spend some quality time with the `bash` man page, and also [the #bash faq](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ).

Comment: Also, note that in the single-quoted sting it wasn't necessary to backslash-escape the quotes: `'F="123"'` instead of `'F=\"123\"'`.

Comment: Thanks!  Makes complete sense.  It's the little details that make a big difference. :-)

Comment: As an alternative to the Bash man page, look here http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/  Under "Select a Volume" in the top left frame, pick "Shell and Utilities", and then in the frame below that, pick "2. The Shell Command Language". This is the spec for how a Unix-compliant shell is supposed to work. It describes the processing of shell code in detail and gives a Yacc-like grammar for it, etc.

Comment: `POMO="no" bash -c 'echo "$POMO" '` Try that and play with POMO... I now get whats happening and why `X=test echo $X` won't work.

Answer (score 7):

Not an answer to the core question, but if anyone is looking to do this inline in a (subjectively) more elegant way than `bash -c`:

```sh
( export MY_FLAG="Hello"; echo "$MY_FLAG" )
```

The syntax is nicer, no escape chars etc.